# How can I get my romance through a two-year breakup?

Tags: novel, plot, romance

My story calls for the main characters to break up for at least two years, before getting back together. (In this particular case, the breakup is for ethical reasons - the relationship began when the two were therapist and patient)

How do I keep them apart but still keep the story going?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Stack Exchange is not like other sites. We require concrete, practical questions which have the potential to help others. As it stands, this question (a) has too many questions (b) is too localized to your story (c) is more of a brainstorming or discussion question, which are both off-topic here. If you want to rewrite this post to focus on "How do I keep my main characters apart for dramatic reasons?", that's something the community can help you with.

Comment: I rephrased this slightly; I suspect it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

She is audited by the ethics arm of the board which gave her her professional license. He's a former patient. The board tells her to break it off or lose her license. In the intervening two years, she realizes that he is worth losing her license for, or alternately finds another job.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing in the first person, you can just continue with the story of the MC and what happens with his/her life during that time.

If you're writing in the third person, you can try to combine both stories during the time. Is he still the therapist during the two years and they "only" break the relationship or do they stop the therapy too? If they stop completely, you can just write their lives separated, each time one chapter or mixing the threads in the same one and divide chapters by "real-story" time.

Comment: I am writing in first person and therapy has ended for five months, but the relationship has not. I need a dramatic way to break them up... She is the therapist by the way.

Comment: Some ideas: 1. he is cheating her with her secretary, 2. the therapist ex-boyfriend re-appears in her life and the patient is jelous, so after an argue they broke up or decide to "take a time" (this idea can occur just in the opposite way), 3. She discover he is married even when they're having a relationship, 4. Problems with the family.

Comment: Just think about people you know and why or how did they break up with their expartners.

Comment: They love each other too much to let something small break them up. So it has to be something neither of them can control. And it has to have the potential to keep them apart of years...

Comment: She is audited by the ethics arm of the board which gave her her professional license. He's a former patient. The board tells her to break it off or lose her license. In the intervening two years, she realizes that he is worth losing her license for, or alternately finds another job.

Comment: I could kiss you Lauren! Thanks a bunch! I kept trying to find a way for her to keep practicing, but he is filthy rich and so is she, she does not need to work! Yay!

Comment: I couldn't see this because she is a fixer and she had her mom (which was why she became a psychiatrist inn the first place.)and one more of her friends parents to help. Her mother more than anyone, he can't understand why she won't give up her license and she thinks he should understand.

Comment: He wants her to choose him but she chooses her mum and he goes away. He had been considering it for a while, being free of his father.(this way he gets to settle his demons as well!) He gives her one more chance then packs up and goes to live a life he has only dreamed of, with his brother who is a highly skilled bounty hunter for the government and wildly rich people. Wow I have to get back to writing! again thank you sooooooooooo much!

Comment: @Lauren, you haven't actually posted an answer, just a comment.  You could fix that. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio HA! you're right; I'm an idiot. That'll teach me to multi-task. :)

Answer (score 0):

They could each join the same social group, on accident (one character is already a member; the other then joins, not knowing). This would force them into proximity, which would generate conflict and tension dependant upon their initial split. You could ride this tension for a full two years, or introduce it later on -- a year in, or six months -- so that it could catalyze their eventual reunion, with a resolution or "snapping" of that tension.

If not: there's always pining, nostalgic longing, looking melancholically at pictures. Etc.

Good luck!